# The free group II$_{\infty}$ factor isomorphism problem

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\Gamma$ be an infinite discrete group, and $H = l^{2}(\Gamma)$ the separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space.
Let $\rho$ be the left regular representation of $\Gamma$ on $H$.

**Definition** : Let $L(\Gamma) := \rho (\Gamma)''$ the von Neumann algebra generated by $\Gamma$.

**Proposition** :  $L(\Gamma)$ is a $II_{1}$ factor iff $\Gamma$ is ICC (infinite conjugacy class).

Let $\Gamma = \mathbb{F}_{n} = \langle a_{1}, a_{2},..., a_{n} \vert   \rangle$  the free group with $n$ generator. It's ICC iff $n \geq 2$.

**Free group factor isomorphism problem** : $L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) ≃ L(\mathbb{F}_{m})$, $∀n,m≥2$ ?

**Voiculescu's formula** (see [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=A9C36B7AC7537F510D02C9A364E65E4D?doi=10.1.1.49.1853&rep=rep1&type=pdf) p 3) :  $L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{(n-1)k^{2}+1}) \otimes M_{k}(\mathbb{C})$

**Example**:  $L(\mathbb{F}_{2}) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{5}) \otimes M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$

**Corollary**: $\bigotimes_{i} L(\mathbb{F}_{n_{i}})   \simeq \bigotimes_{i} L(\mathbb{F}_{m_{i}})$ if $\prod_{i}(n_{i}-1) = \prod_{i}(m_{i}-1)$

**Observation** : $L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \otimes B(H) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{(n-1)k^{2}+1}) \otimes M_{k}(\mathbb{C}) \otimes B(H) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{(n-1)k^{2}+1})  \otimes B(H)$

However, "$\exists k_{1}, k_{2} $ : $(n-1)k_{1}^{2}+1 = (m-1)k_{2}^{2}+1$" $\Leftrightarrow$  "$(n-1)(m-1)$ is a square".

**Corollary**: $L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \otimes B(H) \simeq  L(\mathbb{F}_{m}) \otimes B(H)$   if $(n-1)(m-1)$ is a **square**.

> **Question** :  Is it known to be true in general : $L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \otimes B(H) \simeq  L(\mathbb{F}_{m}) \otimes
>  B(H)$ $\forall n, m \ge 2$ ?
>   (if "no", is it equivalent to the *free group factor isomorphism problem* ?)

**In general**:  $L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{m})^{\alpha} $ with  $\alpha = (\frac{m-1}{n-1})^{1/2}$.

**Definition**: Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $II_{1}$ factor, then $\mathcal{M}^{t} \simeq p(M_{k}(\mathbb{C}) \otimes  \mathcal{M})p \simeq q(B(H) \otimes  \mathcal{M})q$,
 with $q \in B(H) \otimes  \mathcal{M}$ and $p \in M_{k}(\mathbb{C}) \otimes  \mathcal{M}$ projections, $Tr(q) = t$,  $k=\lceil t \rceil$ and $\tau(p) = \frac{t}{k}$.

**Remark** : Let $n, m \ge 2$ such that $(n-1)(m-1)$ is a square.
Let the $II_{\infty}$ factor $\mathcal{N} \simeq  L(\mathbb{F}_{n}) \otimes B(H) \simeq  L(\mathbb{F}_{m}) \otimes B(H)$.
Let $Tr$ (resp. $Tr'$) be the trace on $\mathcal{N}_{+}$ coming from the unique trace of $L(\mathbb{F}_{n})$ (resp. $L(\mathbb{F}_{m})$).
Let the projection $p, q \in \mathcal{N}$ such that $Tr(p) = Tr'(q) = 1$.
Then  $p \mathcal{N} p \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{n})$ and $q \mathcal{N} q \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{m})$. So, $Tr' = \alpha Tr$ with  $\alpha = (\frac{n-1}{m-1})^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

Radulescu introduced the interpolated free group factors $L(\mathbb{F}_r)$ for all $1<r<\infty$. They obey the rule that if $r\in\mathbb{N}$ then we get the proper free group factor and they also obey,

$L(\mathbb{F}_r)^s=L(\mathbb{F}_{r'})$ where $r'={1+\frac{r-1}{s^2}}$. This gives that all free group factors are amplifications of each other. Which implies that they all generate the same $II_\infty$ factors. (ie $L(\mathbb{F}_n)\overline\otimes\mathcal{B(H)}\simeq L(\mathbb{F}_m)\overline\otimes\mathcal{B(H)} $.

Further, this reduces the free group factor isomorphism problem to the calculation of the fundamental groups one of the finite free group factors.

It is known that it is either

I.) All of $\mathbb{R}^+$ in which case they are all isomorphic.

II.) Or $\{1\}$, in which case they are all non-isomorphic.

Here is part of Dykema's thesis where this is proved.

http://arxiv.org/pdf/funct-an/9211012v1.pdf

Comment: Yes: but you need the fact about interpolated free group factors to get the result about fundamental groups.

Comment: Yes, you're right !

Comment: The details runs exactly as your comment [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136411/whats-the-natural-equivalence-of-subfactors-in-general/136424#comment351943_136424). I'm thoughless, I should have remembered it... : we restrict to $s  \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, $L(\mathbb{F}_{r})^{s} = p ( L(\mathbb{F}_{r} \otimes B(H) )p$. Then, $L(\mathbb{F}_{r})^{s} \otimes B(H) \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{r}) \otimes B(H) \otimes  (qB(H)q) $ $ \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{r}) \otimes B(H)$, because $qB(H)q \simeq M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: **There is a point I don't understand** : take $s \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ is not sufficient, because even with free interpolated group factors, we just prove that $L(\mathbb{F}_{r}) \otimes B(H)  \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{s}) \otimes B(H)$ if $(s-1)/(r-1)$ or $(r-1)/(s-1)$ is a square interger. The problem is that we can't take $s  \not\in \mathbb{N}$ because $B(H)$ is a $I_{\infty}$ factor, and so, it can't absorb a projection with a non-integer trace, as $\mathcal{R}$ [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136411/whats-the-natural-equivalence-of-subfactors-in-general/136424#comment351943_136424)

Comment: So "$L(\mathbb{F}_{r}) \otimes \mathcal{R}  \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{s}) \otimes \mathcal{R}, r,s>1$" it's ok for me, but "$L(\mathbb{F}_{r}) \otimes B(H)  \simeq L(\mathbb{F}_{s}) \otimes B(H)$", still not... and for you ?

Comment: Yes, the key is that if you have a $II_1$-factor $M$ acting on $\mathcal{K}$ then the isomorphism type of $M'$ is uniquely determined by dim$_M\mathcal{K}$. So for example if dim$_M\mathcal{K}=\infty$ then $M'\simeq M^{op}\otimes B(H)$. Now if we cut everything down by $p$ then we get $p\mathcal{K}$ is an infinite dimensional $pMp$ module so the commutant is $pMp\otimes B(H)$, however you can also get this by cutting $M'$ by $p$, but since $p$ commutes with $M'$ it doesn't change the isomorphism type. Hopefully this clarifies.

Comment: A sort heuristic argument is that you should think of a $II_1$ factor as a "square" because it's a diffuse version of a finite matrix. Then a $II_\infty$ factor is like an "infinite square" pieced together from many copies of the same finite square. In this analogy, I always like to say that "a $II_\infty$ factor is a $II_1$ quilt". and the isomorphism I describe is just saying that what matters is the quilt, not where we do the stitching. Hopefully, this makes some sense.

Comment: Ok, thank you Owen for these technical and heuristical arguments ! So in general, if $\mathcal{M}$ is a $II_{1}$ factor, then $\mathcal{M}^{t} \otimes B(H) \simeq \mathcal{M} \otimes B(H)$. It's good to have this in mind.

Comment: Yes!, exactly right.