# The recent development of the free group factor problem

Tags: reference-request, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am interested in operator algebras, especially in the free group factor problem. Are there any literature reviews of the free group factor problem? Since Wikipedia does not have an entry about this problem, it is even difficult to find the possible approach to the problem. May anyone provide some references for that?

Comment: This site has several posts about it, e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458047/the-free-group-ii-infty-factor-isomorphism-problem). Is this what you are interested in? [This MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138318/about-generator-and-isomorphism-problems-for-free-groups-operator-algebras) is by the same author.

Comment: In fact I have read these two posts, and they are high-quality posts. But what I prefer are articles that systematically studied the problem. Better if they are published in some way.

Comment: I'm not aware of any recent review articles on the topic, but I'd also be interested in an answer.